# Do I really need a Remote Service to run work in the background?

Tags: android

My android application is a running app.  My professor is a bit confusing at times. When the running application is not on the screen such as when the user presses that home button, the application still should be able to do work such as track the user's steps and distance.

My professor stated that a Remote Service is only way of doing this. According to the slides he provided, you would create an AIDL file and implemented it inside your service.

Here is pictures from the slides:

[image]
[image]

I've been able to do it without the AIDL and the application has been able to track my fake location on the emulator without any problems.

Do I really need a remote service.

Comment: your "remote" means "not local"? do you mean the service with `android:process=":remote"` in the manifest?

Comment: yes. that is the manifest in his slides. I don't know why he wanted us to do that.

Comment: no you dont need it, it can be local and in this case you can still use AIDL or use "bound local service" pattern

Answer (score 0):

You are right.Even simple started service runs beyond the ui interaction,untill you manually stop that service.(yes system may kill your service at low memory)

Answer (score 0):

Remote service is needed only for that reason in his naming. For remote actions with other applications, because you can't provide simpler access in that case.

In your case `IntentService` or `Service` with work is performed in thread which have been manually created would be enough.

Note, that simple `Service` runs on Ui thread.